# How can I fix this error related to Unique Non-Clustered index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table is called `SalFactorHds`, it has an unique index on column `FactorNumFHS`. While inserting values into the table I see this error:

> cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.salfactorHds' with unique index UQ_FactorNumFHS

`@FactorNumFHS` is the parameter that stored procedure is sending.

The former code was this :

```
INSERT INTO SaLFactorHds (FactorNumFHS , column1 , columnb)
VALUES(@FactorNumFHS, 1, 2)
```

I changed it into this :

```
INSERT INTO SaLFactorHds (FactorNumFHS, column1 , columnb)
VALUES( (CASE
           WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM SALFactorHds
                            WHERE FactorNumFHS = @FactorNumFHS) 
             THEN @FactorNumFHS
             ELSE ISNULL((SELECT MAX(FactorNumFHS)
                          FROM SALFactorHds  
                          WHERE (CompanyNo = @CompanyNoFHS) 
                            AND (FactorNumFHS <= (SELECT MaxNormalFactorSFT 
                                                  FROM SALFactorTypes 
                                                  WHERE CompanyNo = @CompanyNoFHS 
                                                    AND (@FactorTypeFHS = SerialNoSFT)))
                            AND (FiscalYear = @YearFHS)) ,0) + 1
          END), 1, 2)
```

but I still see that error !!

Comment: What is the question?. the Unique index will not allow a duplicate to get inserted.

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally flawed.... on a busy system, doing a `SELECT MAX() + 1` is **NEVER** going to work without duplicates! Just imagine you have multiple connections working on your system, and all of them want to insert a row - each one of them will most likely get the **same value** for `MAX() + 1` and then try to insert those....... you should use a **robust** numbering system, e.g. something like the `IDENTITY` column in SQL Server tables. Don't roll your own - it's just bound to fail....